# Dynamic array in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, dynamic

I have SQL parameter array as...

SqlParameter[] sqlParams = new SqlParameter[2];

If I want to add more parameters, Can I add to the current array ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No you cannot append elements. In .NET arrays are static. If you want dynamic collections you could use a generic [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) to which you could add elements dynamically.

```
var sqlParams = new List<SqlParameter>();
sqlParams.Add(param1);
sqlParams.Add(param2);
...

// convert to a static array if needed
SqlParameter[] result = sqlParams.ToArray();
```

Comment: & you can Use .ToArray() if you need to

Comment: But, How do I pass it to "Parameters" property of sqlCommand ?

Comment: @Anish, he showed you how to convert to an array afterwards.  `sqlCommand.Parameters.AddRange(sqlParams.ToArray());`

Answer (score 3):

Probably better to use a System.Collections.Generic.List<>

```
List<SqlParameter> sqlParams = new List<SqlParameter>();
sqlParams.Add(x);
sqlParams.Add(y);
sqlParams.Add(z);
```

If you need an array, you can always go:

```
sqlParams.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I would just use the built in Parameters property of SqlCommand.

```
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection connection 
        = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("connection string goes here");
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();

    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter parameter = command.CreateParameter();
    parameter.ParameterName = "@ParameterName";
    parameter.DbType = DbType.String;
    parameter.Value = "Some String Value";

    command.Parameters.Add(parameter);
```

Then later, if you need to access them, you can do so by:

```
SqlParameter param = command.Parameters[0];
```

That way you don't have to mess with adding a range and keeping track of a separate array or List<>.